# How to print all the elements of an array that are inputed with all the initialized zeros removed?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public String toString(){
    String allstr="";
    for (int i=0 ; i<this.myArray.length; i++){ 
    }

    for (int i=capacity-1 ; i>=0 ; i--){
        allstr=(this.myArray[i] + " ") + allstr ;
    }
    return allstr;
}
```

this code prints all the elements of my array including the 0 that are initialized. how can i exclude them? remember that my programm allows to input 0 in the array. So inputed zeros =/= initialized zeros. for example if an array has 5 3 2 1 0 0 -1 and the first zero is inputed by me how i can remove the second zero which is there because of the initialization of my array. Τhe code above is a part of a project. Just a method.

Comment: Your first for loop isn't doing anything... Secondly, is myArray an integer-array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if your array is something like this:

```
int[] myArray = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

You can create boolean array. Let's say that true value is if it's inputed by user, and false if it' initialized.

```
boolean[] isChanged = {false, false, false, false, false};
```

Every time you change or input a new value in array you just need to mark this value as "changed"

```
isChanged[i] = true;
```

Than your method toString() will be

```
public String toString(){
    String allstr="";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.myArray.length; i++){
        if (isChanged[i] == true) 
            allstr = allstr + (this.myArray[i] + " ");
    }

    return allstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is to use `List<Integer>` in place of static array.

Read here about [ArrayList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Sample code:

```
List<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        myArray.add((int) ((Math.random() * 5) + 1));
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray.toArray(new Integer[] {})).replaceAll(
        "[\\[,\\]]", ""));
```

Comment: hm forgot to mention that the user can input all possible values. so that will not work unfortunately. Also i have to initialize the array with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array of `int`, there is no way to tell the difference between the value you set to zero, and the one initialized to it.  However, if you create, instead, an array of 
`Integer`s, you will be able to differentiate between 0 and null.

for instance, using `Integer`:

```
Integer[] list = new Integer[3];
list[0] = 1;
list[1] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(list[i]);
}
```

output

```
1
0
null
```

compared to using `int`:

```
int[] list = new int[3];
list[0] = 1;
list[1] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(list[i]);
}
```

output:

```
1
0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is an array of primitive numbers (like `int`), then there is simply no way to distinguish between zeroes placed during initialization and zeroes resulting from input. You could use something else to keep track, like a parallel array of `boolean` to keep track of whether the value was from input, or a list of elements that were input.

Another approach would be to use an array of `Number` objects, and use a special one to represent the initial zero, like `BigInteger.ZERO`. All others from input would be `Integer` or `BigDecimal`. By using different classes for initialized versus input, there is less chance for mixup. BTW, you should use the for-each syntax, and a `StringBuilder` if you're building a string iteratively.

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;
for (Number num : array) {
  if (num != BigInteger.ZERO) {
    if (first) {
      first = false;
    }
    else {
      buf.append(' ');
    }
    buf.append(num);
  }
}
return buf.toString();
```

Instead of building the string manually, you might use any of the various equivalents for String.join that Java does not have, provided by different third-party libraries.